# svn checkout not working via phing

Tags: php, svn, phing

I'm currently trying to write an internal application to be able to deploy our projects to acceptance and production servers with a single click.
We are using phing to accomplish this.

At the moment I'm having difficulty checking out (or doing an svn export) the project. I use the following command:

```
<exec command="svn checkout ${svn.host} ${svn.exportdir} --force --username server --password <password>"  />
```

on a normal command line this works perfectly, however i get prompted to accept a certificate because the host uses https. Problem is there seems to be no parameter to automatically accept a certificate.

the --trust-server-cert doesn't help either, becase the certificate is rejected due to a hostname mismatch, where the parameter only bypasses a "CA is unknown"-error.

Any ideas on how I can check out (or export, update, ...) the project?

Comment: Make sure you also pass ``--non-interactive`` to stop your command from waiting on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `wget` on the svn servers HTTPS adress and accept the certificate permanently.

```
$ wget https://svn.mydomain.com/repos
```

And then press <kbd>p</kbd> to accept the cert.

---

I also added some hints to the [PHP documentation about the problems with certificates](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-auth-set-parameter.php#104300):

Simply call

```
svn checkout https://svn.mydomain.com/repos --force --username server --password iMPs+nana0kIF
```

on your command line and accept the cert.

---

There could be still a problem when the user which executes the Phing command is not root, then you have to execute this command as the user which runs the Phing command:

```
su wwwrun wget https://... 
su wwwrun svn checkout https://...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do one manual checkout as the user that will be running phing. You can checkout to `/dev/null` if you want to. Once you have accepted the certificate, it will stay accepted (if that user has a `.subversion` directory to store it).

By the way, any specific reason why you are using the `svn` commandline interface through and `ExecTask` instead of just using the [`SvnCheckoutTask`](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html#SvnCheckoutTask) directly?